# Having a paypal calculating VAT issue?

Tags: paypal

I am developing a simple shopping cart with paypal checkout, but i am stuck with the VAT processing part on paypal's side.

Paypal seems to add up total +VAT+ shipping. But when i substract the VAT from the $grandtotal variable in my shopping cart i get the error message:

> The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

I am using Paypal's SetExpressCheckout.

My questions:
1/ for parameter PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT should i use the total with or without the VAT
2/ should i use parameter PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT? if so how do i prevent paypal from adding it up

regards

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following extracts from the [PayPal site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) :

- > **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT** - (Required) Total cost of the transaction to the
  >   buyer. If shipping cost and tax charges are known, include them in
  >   this value. If not, this value should be the current sub-total of the
  >   order. If the transaction includes one or more one-time purchases,
  >   this field must be equal to the sum of the purchases. Set this field
  >   to 0 if the transaction does not include a one-time purchase such as
  >   when you set up a billing agreement for a recurring payment that is
  >   not immediately charged. When the field is set to 0, purchase-specific
  >   fields are ignored.
- > **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT** - Sum of cost of all items in this order. For digital goods, this field is required. You can specify up to 10
  >   payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9, inclusive; except for
  >   digital goods, which supports single payments only.
- > **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT** - (Optional) Sum of tax for all items in this order. You can specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit
  >   between 0 and 9, inclusive; except for digital goods, which supports
  >   single payments only.

Answer (score 1):

AMT = item amt + tax amt + shipping amt + handle amt - discount.

So if your item amt already includes tax, then don't use tax amt, otherwise, make sure item amt doesn't include tax and put tax in tax amt.